# Opening a Hyperion SQR Reporting

Tags: hyperion, sqr

I have received some files with SQR extension. When I open it with Hyperion SQR Reporting tool, it shows only a script. How can we view the report layout using this script and how can we run this report. I'm not able to get a proper help doc on designing and executing a SQR report. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

From the command line you can run on Windows:

```
sqrw filename username/password@servername -KEEP
```

On Linux:

```
sqr filename username/password@servername -KEEP
```

Some more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28394_01/pt852pbh1/eng/psbooks/tsqr/chapter.htm?File=tsqr/htm/tsqr02.htm)